# UIButton.titleLabel clipping text problem

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uilabel, clipping

Hope I can get some help with a rather obscure problem with UILabel. I keep getting problems with clipping of characters. The font in the image at the link below is baskerville-bolditalic. The yellow is the rect that the UIButton is rendered in. The yellow is the UIButton's titleLabel.backgroundColor.

http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/2381/screenshot20100813at235.png

Here is the code:

```
    UIButton * currentCharacter = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    currentCharacter.frame = cFrame;
    currentCharacter.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        currentCharacter.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        currentCharacter.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
        currentCharacter.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        currentCharacter.titleLabel.minimumFontSize = 1;
        currentCharacter.titleLabel.font = currentFont;
        currentCharacter.titleLabel.clipsToBounds = NO;
        currentCharacter.clipsToBounds = NO;

        currentCharacter.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        currentCharacter.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Maybe I'm just misunderstanding adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth. Thanks a ton in advance!